# Retornar el caracter central si la cantidad de caracteres es impar y si es par devolver los 2 caracteres centrales

Tags: javascript

Lo que debe retornar es al ejecutarse es el caracter central si la cantidad de caracteres  es impar y si es par devolver los 2 caracteres centrales , lo que debe retornar es "es".

```
(function getMiddle(s)
 {
 var name = s;
 var name2 = s.length;
 if(name2%2 === 0){
  var valor1= (name2/2)-1; 
  var valor2=(name2/2)+1;
return name.slice(valor1,valor2);
}else{
  var valor1=(name2-1)/2; 
  var valor2=(name2+1)/2;
 return name.slice(valor1,valor2);
 }
}("test"));
```

Comment: Hola, pero ya te devuelve "es", ¿que más necesitas? Quizá no entendí bien tu pregunta.

Comment: Si vas a usar Stack Snippet el código debería mostrar algo al hacer clic en el botón ejecutar de otra forma no tiene sentido. Por otro lado el título no ayuda a tu pregunta, este debería ser un resumen de lo que estás preguntando.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso , ese mismo codigo cuando lo pego en codewars ya que es un problema de esa pagina , devuelve error .

Comment: Pues  en el navegador funciona perfectamente. Quiza te de error por que es una función cerrada, no me acuerdo exactamente como se llaman esas funciones cerradas por paréntesis y desde fuera no puedan  acceder a ella otras funciones de la pagina, de ahi el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a Mozilla Developer Network, las funciones entre paréntesis se conocen como [funciones autojecutables](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE) o en inglés como [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

La forma de usar la función en Stack Snippet es asignar a una variable la función autoejecutable y luego hacer lo que se requiera hacer con dicha variable. Por simplicidad en el siguiente ejemplo se muestra el resultado en la consola.

Nótese que el resultado es `es`

```js
var salida = (function getMiddle(s)
 {
 var name = s;
 var name2 = s.length;
 if(name2%2 === 0){
  var valor1= (name2/2)-1; 
  var valor2=(name2/2)+1;
return name.slice(valor1,valor2);
}else{
  var valor1=(name2-1)/2; 
  var valor2=(name2+1)/2;
 return name.slice(valor1,valor2);
 }
}("test"));

console.info(salida)
```

NOTA: Una forma abreviada de hacer lo mismo es la siguiente:

```js
function getMiddle(texto){
  return (texto.length % 2)? texto.substr(texto.length/2,1):texto.substr(texto.length/2 - 1,2);
}

console.info(getMiddle("test"));
```